# Can't ssh to my server with high latency time

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

This is the message when I ping the server IP. I stated to get this problem in the past few days, and when this occurs, I can't ssh to the server, after the 'time' increases to this level after about 10 minutes. The 'time' starts at below 10ms, in which time i can ssh, but then I can't.

```
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1117 ttl=64 time=256.304 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1118 ttl=64 time=80.418 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1119 ttl=64 time=43.204 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1120 ttl=64 time=123.362 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1121 ttl=64 time=142.950 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1122 ttl=64 time=164.194 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1123 ttl=64 time=188.428 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1124 ttl=64 time=208.295 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1125 ttl=64 time=286.574 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1126 ttl=64 time=309.130 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1127 ttl=64 time=68.551 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1128 ttl=64 time=36.732 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1129 ttl=64 time=42.148 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1130 ttl=64 time=129.112 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1131 ttl=64 time=156.540 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1132 ttl=64 time=180.849 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1133 ttl=64 time=204.715 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1134 ttl=64 time=286.358 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1135 ttl=64 time=310.540 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1136 ttl=64 time=42.223 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1137 ttl=64 time=91.850 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1138 ttl=64 time=40.754 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1139 ttl=64 time=130.153 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1140 ttl=64 time=157.485 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1141 ttl=64 time=171.732 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1142 ttl=64 time=191.513 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1143 ttl=64 time=274.098 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1144 ttl=64 time=298.063 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1145 ttl=64 time=317.264 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1146 ttl=64 time=75.745 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1147 ttl=64 time=94.864 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1148 ttl=64 time=122.503 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1149 ttl=64 time=149.437 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1150 ttl=64 time=169.521 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1151 ttl=64 time=187.885 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.10.189: icmp_seq=1152 ttl=64 time=270.024 ms
```

My colleague can log into the server with stable 'time'.

This looks like it's a problem of my IP address. But why does it gradually worsen the situation?

Comment: Interesting question. Does your latency ( the correct word for "time") only go up when using ash? When its high for SSH, is it high to other servers?  [ Speculating wildly , I wonder if you have an issue with your router connection tracking ]

Comment: Use traceroute to maybe find out where the latency occurs?

Answer (score 0):

- You could try setting an A RECORD for you IP
  Example: SRV01.SERNAME.COM
- Then check if ready @: https://dnschecker.org/
- Then change your SSH port to something other then the default 22
  EXAMPLE: 37378

Kind Regards
Francho